# usage of select statement in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

```
Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(true, CUSTOMER_TABLE_NAME, 
      new String[] {GENERIC_ID_KEY, ADDRESS_KEY, PHONE_KEY, EMAIL_KEY,CUSTOMER_NAME_KEY},
      GENERIC_ID_KEY + "=" + customerDbId, null,
      null, null, null, null);
```

How should I modify this command if GENERIC_ID_KEY  and  customerDbId is string.
I tried using like in b/w but still negative results, n error is thrown.

Comment: what error message is thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if customerDbId  is a string type then place it in between quote

as

```
GENERIC_ID_KEY + "= '" + customerDbId + "'"
```

Comment: This is  very dangerous. Why not use the default sql escaping of android: `GENERIC_ID_KEY + "=?", new String { customerDbId },..`

Comment: what you want to say @BorisStrandjev buddy

Comment: If you append the string value like you propose you risk SQLInjection. The correct way of making the query is: `Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(true, CUSTOMER_TABLE_NAME, new String[] {GENERIC_ID_KEY,ADDRESS_KEY, PHONE_KEY, MAIL_KEY,CUSTOMER_NAME_KEY}, GENERIC_ID_KEY + "=?", new String []{ customerDbId}, null, null, null, null);` Using the where args parameters is safer.

Comment: I used it as GENERIC_ID_KEY + "**like** '" + customerDbId + "'" and it worked..thnkss

Answer (score 0):

It's a cursor problem. Be sure curser is the first state before selection.